# How do I add a full width block to magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9.1

I'm very new to Magento so please keep that in mind. I didn't see this question asked here before so here goes...

I want to add a full width image on the top of some of my category pages and cms pages. This will be under the main navigation. This is not my website but an example of what I mean (http://www.sixpackbags.com/ambassadors/. I can make the cms pages full width but then the content is as well and then it adds padding under the navigation as well. Any one know how I achieve this?

Again I want the position on all pages(categories and cms) and be able to put different images in every position.

I wasn't sure if I could use "breadcrumb position" or had to make my own? If I do have to make my own. How do I do this?

I really appreciate any help I can get from any one on here. Thank you so much!

Comment: you might customize the styles.css for that full width layout.

Comment: I'm assuming it would be in the theme files somewhere. But the category pages are not set to full width. Product pages have a sidebar with all the other categories. How would I do that?

Comment: You will probably need to add a new block to the page template with XML. I doubt CSS will do the trick for most Magento templates.

Answer (score 0):

for add a image to category pages you can use default category "image" attribute navigate to Admin->Catalog->Manage Categories -> select appropriate category from the left sidebar->Genaral Information -> Find the image field and upload the image there . If you using default magento theme the image should display by now please check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=feYgON2P-pQ) for more info . If you are using custom template you will need some coding also.

for cms pages follow this [guide](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-create-and-edit-static-blocks)

to make the image full width you have to edit theme style sheet located in

```
root/skin/frontend/your_theme/default/css/styles.css
```

Comment: I already put the image in the default spot in the category I just couldn't figure out how to change the image to full width in the css. I need the page content to be contained as is and not full width. Just the image on top. is that possible? I was trying to resize with css and it wouldn't change.

Comment: yes it should be possible, can you post the site link here then I can take a look otherwise it is hard to predict what changes should we done

Comment: Chamal, What we are trying to achieve is this ... http://www.sixpackbags.com/ambassadors/ I want a full width banner but the content contained in container below.

Comment: I have checked your site given above add this class
.carousel-inner .std img{width: 100%;} 
to your style sheet

Comment: I tried setting the width to 100% and it seemed to align right and I couldnt center it. The link above was the website we were trying to mimic the url is <!--http://if-testing.com/isobag-->

Comment: can you please post your URL then I can check and give a solution

Comment: if-testing.com/isobag

Comment: it has an error "The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later."

Comment: I put the maintenance flag up. Its off now, you can check now. Thank you

Comment: I finally figured it out. I set the page to full width. Then for the content to be boxed in our template came with a shortcode for a div centered in the page so text or any other items would not display full width just the main banner. Thank you everyone.

Comment: nice to here , if my answer helped you ,you can accept the answer